# Specflow "No Matching Step Definition Found" but also "All Steps have been defined already"

Tags: visual-studio-2022, specflow

I am unable to run my Specflow tests, in Visual Studio 2022.

I have all steps defined and bound and yet it still says "No Matching Step Definition Found". Yet when I right click on the line and try to "Define Steps", it says "All Steps have been defined already" ?!! So no purple lines etc.

I am using

- VS 2022
- Specflow 3.9.74
- Specflow.MSTest 3.9.74
- Specflow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation 3.9.74

I can't understand why??

Any help gratefully received and appreciated. I've been trying to figure this out for over a day now as it affects the other tests.

Added screenshot here [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Visual Studio and SpecFlow just act weird. If a clean and rebuild doesn't fix the issue, close all Visual Studio windows, then delete the `.vs` folder that resides at the root of your solution.

I've noticed similar problems to this for years, and it usually indicates some mismatch between the C# step definitions, feature files, and the cached mapping between the two in Visual Studio.

Failing that, if using Git, try a "super clean" of your working tree after committing all pending changes:

```
git clean -fdx
```

And of course if that doesn't work, uninstalling and reinstalling the SpecFlow plugin might help too.

Comment: Thankyou, I will try those and report back